# How to change state value in const mode?

Tags: react-native

I am a beginner in React-Native.
I tried to change the state value.
But it seems different with "class" mode. Now I am using "const" mode.
In const mode, how can I change the state value?

```
import React from "react";
import {
   View,
   Text,
   Image,
   TouchableOpacity
} from "react-native";

const Product = props => {
    this.state = {
        checkIconURL : require('../../assets/ic_check_circle.png')
    }
    set = () => {
        this.setState({ checkIconURL : require('../../assets/empty.png') })  //But this lines gives err.
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 16}}>Everyday</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress = {this.set}>
                <Image source = {this.state.checkIconURL} style={{width: 30, height: 30}} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: you can't access ```state``` from the functional component. Use react hooks.

Comment: Add this code inside the class and remove the const, Just simply declare the class it's should work.               
 state = {
        checkIconURL : require('../../assets/ic_check_circle.png')
    }
    set = () => {
        this.setState({ checkIconURL : require('../../assets/empty.png') })  //But this lines gives err.
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

state is not available in function components, this.state and this.setState() can only be used in class component, u have to use useState hook from react to use the state...

```
import React ,{ useState } from "react";
import {
    View,
    Text,
    Image,
    TouchableOpacity
} from "react-native";

const Product = props => {
   const initialState = require('../../assets/ic_check_circle.png');
   const [iconUrl, setIconUrl ]  = useState(initialState);

   const set = () => {
       const emptyImageUrl = require('../../assets/empty.png')
          setIconUrl(emptyImageUrl);
    }

   return (
       <View>
           <Text style={{ fontSize: 16}}>Everyday</Text>
               <TouchableOpacity onPress = {set}>
                   <Image source = {iconUrl} style={{width: 
                       30, height: 30}} />
               </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the following code is incorrect as you need to use Hook in a functional component to manage state.
React provides the useState hook to manage state in a functional component.

```
import React ,{ useState } from "react";
import {
    View,
    Text,
    Image,
    TouchableOpacity
} from "react-native";

const Product = props => {
   const initialState = require('../../assets/ic_check_circle.png');
   const [ state,setState ]  = useState({checkIconURL: initialState});
   set = () => {
       const emptyImageUrl = require('../../assets/empty.png') });
           setState({...state, checkIconURL: emptyImageUrl })
       }

   return (
       <View>
           <Text style={{ fontSize: 16}}>Everyday</Text>
               <TouchableOpacity onPress = {this.set}>
                   <Image source = {this.state.checkIconURL} style={{width: 
                       30, height: 30}} />
               </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
    )
}
```